# How to notify UITestcase from the Project file Swift

Tags: swift, xctestcase

Im am trying to post a notification from my project and then add an observer in my UITestCase file.
But it doesn't get called.

Any alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292685/how-to-write-unit-test-for-nsnotification

Comment: Hi, basically what I require is if there is an error in my response I will notify the uitest case and the observer there will call a method in uitestcase file with  code --- XCTFail("Error: \(notification.userInfo?["resp"])")